# Access Sorry Cypress publicly from AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, cypress, amazon-eks

I have an AWS EKS cluster where I am trying to deploy sorry-cypress and my test cases. When I am running the Docker image locally then I am able to access the sorry-cypress dashbaord on my browser but when I am deploying the same docker in EKS then sorry-cypress dashboard is not publicly accessible. Can someone please help me what I am doing wrong here? Below is my Dockerfile content

```
FROM cypress/browsers:node14.7.0-chrome84

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash cypress
RUN install -d -m 0777 -o cypress -g cypress /app
RUN chown cypress:cypress /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash admin
RUN chown -R root:root /app
RUN chmod 755 /app
USER root
ENV CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER="/app/.cypress"
ENV CI=true

# USER cypress

# install dependencies
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
# confirm that Cypress was installed correctly
RUN npx cypress verify

# copy files required by yarn tasks
COPY cypress.json ./
# copy reporter config, used to output JUnit XML
COPY tsconfig.json ./
# copy tests
COPY cypress cypress
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["npx" , "cypress" , "run"]
```